# Slicers in SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, business-intelligence, slice

**Need to Implement Excel Like Slicer in SSRS :**

Hi, I am very new to SSRS. Anyway to implement Excel like Slicers in SSRS?

I have already tried this link [http://www.sqljason.com/search?q=slicers+in+ssrs](http://www.sqljason.com/search?q=slicers%20in%20ssrs), it was bit unclear about the parameters and used analysis service.

But to start, I want to implement it without using analysis service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is use Drill down method:
Action to go on report(same) with specific parameters from grouped matrix. Then just handle dataset, or tables with this parameter, if its empty show all data , if not , show data just by parameter... Best choice is to use hidden parameter with default null...
For example: (We want dynamic slicer not static one)

Note: You need two datasets, one for matrix and one for emblended data

Create new matrix with column group grouped by value that your need in your slicer...

[image]

[image]

Then create Action go to report there and as your parameter pass there value from matrix:

[image]

[image]

When you run report for first time (i mean with default param) you should seems:

[image]

When you click on upper name it should seems(in my example on Alex...):

[image]
It will works only for 1 selected value... You are not able to do multiselects...

Answer (score -1):

For information [Use slicers to filter PivotTable data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-slicers-to-filter-pivottable-data-HA010359466.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i just want to create the slicer functionality in SSRS.